# Could not resolve Datasource to an IP address in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc

I have created AWS lambda function and deployed in AWS. I am getting "Could not resolve Datasource to an IP address" error while connecting Teradata database server located in on-prem from AWS. How to resolve the below mentioned error?

[image]

**Edit:**
     We have rectified "Could not resolve Datasource to an IP address" error currently by using IP address instead of DB instance in DataSource while connecting Teradata database. But when I am trying to connect Teradata database through DB instance i.e., xxx\100 in DataSource, I am getting "Cannot created connection within the time specified" error now.

[image]
   [image]

Comment: You said lambda connects to onpremise db , does it mean it's an internal ? how have you established the communication between aws and on premise, is lambda in vpc , if so, whats the dns server , is it default .2 ?

Comment: It is an internal. Lambda in VPC.

Comment: How does the Lambda function connect to your internal database? Does it go across the Internet, or perhaps a Direct Connect or VPN connection? The main thing to discover is the location of he DNS server that can take the DNS Name of the database and convert it to an IP address. This DNS server would presumably be within your internal network.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, Lambda function is connected to our internal database through direct connect. I have updated my question. Please have a look.

Comment: You will probably need a DNS Resolver. See: [Resolving DNS Queries Between VPCs and Your Network - Amazon Route 53](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resolver.html)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, Could you please add this comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message "Could not resolve Datasource to an IP address" suggests that it is not able to resolve a DNS Name to an IP address.

Seeing that you are connecting to a private datasource, the DNS Name can probably only be resolved internally, via a DNS Server within your organization's network.

This can be done by **DNS Resolver**. From [Resolving DNS Queries Between VPCs and Your Network - Amazon Route 53](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resolver.html):

> When you create a VPC using Amazon VPC, you automatically get DNS resolution within the VPC from Route 53 Resolver... **You can also configure DNS resolution between your VPC and your network over a Direct Connect or VPN connection.**
>
> You can configure Resolver to **forward queries that it receives from EC2 instances in your VPCs to DNS resolvers on your network**. To forward selected queries, you create Resolver rules that specify the domain names for the DNS queries that you want to forward (such as example.com), and the IP addresses of the DNS resolvers on your network that you want to forward the queries to.